# Looking for guidance with MVVM textblock binding on mainviewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have an app that I'm working on relating to stocks.

It is fashioned somewhat like Josh Smith's MVVM demo app with some additions.

I have a data model called ShortQuote.cs
which has a viewmodel `ShortQuoteViewModel`, but the ShortQuoteViewModel is not used right now.

I have a `ShortQuoteRepository` which creates a List of objects of type `ShortQuote` gotten from an XML data file.  The `ShortQuoteRepository` List appears in a tab when the use clicks on a command on the left pane of the mainwindow.

I have a combobox on the `MainWindow` which has a list of ticker symbols.  When the user selects one of these ticker symbols, I want to get one of the StockQuote objects from the ShortQuoteRepository (if it exists for that ticker) and display it's contents in TextBlocks at the top of the `MainWindow` view.

The only way I could get this to work was to expose "new" properties on `MainWindowViewModel` which are mirrors of the properties on the ShortQuote data model, then once I get the `ShortQuote` object from the ShortQuoteRepository I set the `MainWindowViewModel`'s "new" properties equal to those from the retrieved object.  I bind the TextBlock's to the `MainWindowViewModel`'s "new" properties and it works.

I'm feeling like this is a "hack" and that there is a "better" way to accomplish this without having to create the "new" properties on the MainWindowViewModel and am requesting some guidance and suggestions on how to accomplish this in a more straightforward way with just XAML or a combination of XAML and `MainWindowViewModel` code that doesn't require creating these "new" properties.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Somebody else has painstakingly edited your question to add the proper formatting for you, but don't take this as a hint that you can depend on us to fix up your posts every time. This is a friendly warning.

Comment: I appreciate the "reformatting" and will consider this item/question solved and move on...

Answer (score 5):

Also make your ShortQuote a ViewModel (or at least an ObservableObject, if you're using MVVM Light).  Then you can bind `SelectedItem` to a `ShortQuote` property on your viewmodel (mark it as TwoWay).  Then your View can reference the `SelectedItem` as it needs to.

Add this to ShortQuoteViewModel.cs

```
private ShortQuote _selectedQuote;

public ShortQuote SelectedQuote
{    
     get { return _selectedQuote; }
     set
     {
          if(value != _selectedQuote)
          {
               _selectedQuote = value;
               RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedQuote");
          }
      }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Quotes}" SelectedItem={Binding SelectedQuote, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedQuote.Ticker}"/>
```

You'll also have to change your `ShortQuote` class (probably in `ShortQuote.cs`) to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, either by explicitly implementing INPC, or by inheriting from ViewModel or `ObservableObject` (if using MVVM Light.  You didn't specify, but it's popular, and if you aren't using it, you should consider doing so).

*EDIT* Here's a working sample:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="StockQuoteExample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="24"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock>
            <Run Text="Company Name: "/>
            <Run Text="{Binding SelectedTicker.Ticker}"/>
            <Run Text="  Symbol:  "/>
            <Run Text="{Binding SelectedTicker.StockName}"/>
            <Run Text="  Tick Price:  "/>
            <Run Text="{Binding SelectedTicker.TickPrice}"/>
        </TextBlock>

        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding StockQuotes}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTicker, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Width="120" Text="{Binding Ticker}"/>
                        <TextBlock Width="120" Margin="5,0,5,0" Text="{Binding StockName}"/>
                        <TextBlock Width="120" Text="{Binding TickPrice}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Codebehind:

```
using System.Windows;
using StockQuoteExample.ViewModel;

namespace StockQuoteExample
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = new StockQuoteViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using StockQuoteExample.DataModel;

namespace StockQuoteExample.ViewModel
{
    class StockQuoteViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public ObservableCollection<StockQuote> StockQuotes { get; set; }

        private StockQuote _selectedTicker;

        public StockQuote SelectedTicker
        {
            get { return _selectedTicker; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _selectedTicker)
                {
                    _selectedTicker = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("SelectedTicker");
                }
            }
        }


        public StockQuoteViewModel()
        {
            StockQuotes = new ObservableCollection<StockQuote>()
                              {
                                  new StockQuote() {StockName = "Microsoft", TickPrice = 150m, Ticker = "MSFT"},
                                  new StockQuote() {StockName = "Apple", TickPrice = 600m, Ticker = "AAPL"}
                              };
        }




        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    }
}
```

Data Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace StockQuoteExample.DataModel
{
    public class StockQuote : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private string _ticker;

        public string Ticker
        {
            get { return _ticker; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _ticker)
                {
                    _ticker = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Ticker");
                }
            }
        }

        private string _stockName;

        public string StockName
        {
            get { return _stockName; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _stockName)
                {
                    _stockName = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("StockName");
                }
            }
        }

        private decimal _tickPrice;

        public decimal TickPrice
        {
            get { return _tickPrice; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _tickPrice)
                {
                    _tickPrice = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("TickPrice");
                }
            }
        }




        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

Comment: As noted in original question, I already have a ShortQuoteViewModel, but don't understand where or how this might relate to the answer above.

Comment: I'm saying make your ShortQuote implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and expose a ShortQuote property on ShortQuoteViewModel.  That way, when your selected item changes, you don't need to do any manual copying from the selected ShortQuote to display properties in the ShortQuoteViewModel.  I'll edit for some additional clarity.

Comment: ShortQuote.cs (data model) - no change, ShortQuoteViewModel.cs I added the above Property code; MainWindow XAML I added the ListBox and TextBlock.  When I populate the "workspace tab" and then select the first item, I get nothing in my TextBlock.  I put breakpoint on SelectedQuote property set in ShortQuoteViewModel.cs and it doesn't hit.  ShortQuoteViewModel inherits from WorkSpaceViewModel which inherits from ViewModelBase which implements INotifyPropertyChanged.  Am I still missing something? Oh, I changed "RaisePropertyChanged" to "OnPropertyChanged" as that's what Josh's demo code has.

Comment: ShortQuote data model also needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: Thanks for the example, as is it works fine; however, when I attempt to adapt it to my mainwindow structure it doesn't display the values for the selected item.

Comment: As I mentioned in my original post, I'm trying to extend Josh Smith's DemoApp example which has a tabbed pane on the right in which the AllShortQuoteViewModel/ShortQuoteView is displayed and that works fine.  When I select one of the items in the view, it hits my SelectedTicker property code in the viewmodel, and the SelectedTicker is indeed set to a ShortQuote with the correct values, but the binding on the mainwindow display isn't working and nothing is getting displayed.  Ideas?

Comment: Are they two separate windows?  Did you change your ShortQuote Model to implement INPC?

Comment: MainWindow has a menu bar at top, then a button bar, then the textblock in which I want to display the selected values.  On the bottom left is a list of commands for populating the right tab section containing "workspaces" (1 per tab) which are the viewmodel for the shortquotes.  This is all on one window.  The ShortQuote.cs implements INotifyPropertyChanged and the AllShortQuoteViewModel which inherits from WorkspaceViewModel which inherits fom ViewModelBase which implements INotifyPropertyChanged.  When I select on a particular quote line, it hits my SelectedItem property set/get code.

Comment: Without being able to see your code, I'm at the end of my suggestions.  If you'd like to push it out to a repository somewhere I'd be happy to look at it. Or, better yet, if you want to edit your message to include the relevant pieces of your code, that would be fantastic.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far...I've tried some tracing/debugging and I'm getting a message that says BindingExpression path error: 'SelectedQuote' property not found on 'object' 'MainWindowViewModel.  Now the SelectedQuote property is in the AllShortQuoteViewModel which is used to display the list of quotes in the tab pane.  So...any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Not without seeing code at this point.  What that's saying is that the DataContext for the page is set to MainWindowViewModel instead of your AllShortQuoteViewModel.

Comment: I can zip my solution and make it available to you, but don't know how.